# AWS CDN Expire after caching vs deploy

Tags: caching, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

How do I set an AWS CDN to expire after being cached in the user's browser?

The current method expires after it is deployed...

```
Expires: new Date(new Date().getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7))
```

Using Javascript.

Comment: your question is difficult to understand. can you rephrase?

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new to all this, but I'll explain as best I can. Working on deploying a script to CloudFront. I want that script to stay cached for 7 days in the browser. The problem with the above method is that it expires 7 days after deployment, not 7 days after the user GET's the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using Cache-Control: max-age=seconds instead of absolute time if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: Ok so if I want it to cache 7 days out from the moment the user downloads it, I would set Cache-Control to 7 days, correct?

Comment: Yes, set is to 604800 seconds. Both browser and CloudFront must comply with this setting. Note that this is the maximum time it could stay in cache, there are no guarantees when the object will be evicted from any of these caches - it might happen earlier

Comment: Ok cool thanks! So just to be clear, to set that in Javascript I would do  `CacheControl: 'max-age=60604800' `